# Selenium Actions.movetoElement - org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver, geckodriver

I have a scenario where I have to hover over a menu link and click on the drop down sub menus. The code that I'm using is below:

```
public void changeLanguageTest() throws InterruptedException
    {
        WebElement LanguageMenu = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".change-language>button"));
        action.moveToElement(LanguageMenu);
        WebElement mongolianLang = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".change-language>ol>li:nth-child(3)>a"));
        action.moveToElement(mongolianLang).click().build().perform();
        Thread.sleep(3000L);
    }
```

But when I run this code, It fails with an error message :-

> org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: POST
>   /session/3077f893-d9ab-487d-b09f-c5bcd135ea31/moveto did not match a
>   known command

I tried below mentioned code too but no success and same error occurred.

```
BaseClass.action.moveToElement(LanguageMenu).moveToElement(mongolianLang).click().build().perform();
```

I'm using `webdriver v2.53` and running it on `FF v47.0.1`.

Comment: What version of `geckodriver` are you using??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a [bug logged here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/233) `geckodriver` does not yet implement `actions`. The actions we will implement are those being defined right now in the [`W3C WebDriver standard`](https://github.com/w3c/webdriver/) and not those of Selenium.

Selenium has said they will provide a [`Selenium-to-W3C-WebDriver`](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html#actions) shim for actions, but this may take some time to produce after we have made our implementation. Implementation in `geckodriver/Marionette` has not yet started.

---

As [mentioned here from v0.12.0 of `geckodriver`](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.12.0), Implemented routing for [`new actions API`](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html#actions), **but it too is not yet fully implemented in Marionette**

---

You should upgrade your [`geckodriver`](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases).

Comment: Thank you Saurabh for the useful info.