# Drag and drop not working with selenium 3 and firefox driver

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I am working with `selenium webdriver` with `java`.

The issue that I faced is **Drag and drop not working** with `selenium 3` and `firefox driver`

I'm getting the below error:

> org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: POST /session/92189939-94cc-4327-bfb0-72d66621d2f2/moveto did not match a known command
>   Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:43:45 -0700'
>   System info: host: 'TADT063', ip: '192.168.0.195', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_20'
>   Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
>   Capabilities [{moz:profile=C:\Users\Amrutha.U\AppData\Local\Temp\rust_mozprofile.l2Myb7jgbekD, rotatable=false, timeouts={implicit=0, page load=300000, script=30000}, pageLoadStrategy=normal, platform=ANY, specificationLevel=0, moz:accessibilityChecks=false, acceptInsecureCerts=false, browserVersion=52.0, platformVersion=6.1, moz:processID=4308, browserName=firefox, platformName=windows_nt}]
>   Session ID: 92189939-94cc-4327-bfb0-72d66621d2f2

Can anybody help me?

Code :

```
public void selectQuestions() throws InterruptedException, AWTException {

    Thread.sleep(3000);
    WebElement selectquestions = webElement("VAR_SELECTTOP5QUESTIONS");
    selectquestions.click();
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    Action drag = builder.clickAndHold(webElement("VAR_SELECTQUESTIONS")).build();
    drag.perform();
    Point coordinates = webElement("VAR_SELECTEDQUESTIONS").getLocation();
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.mouseMove(coordinates.getX() + 280, coordinates.getY() + 120);
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    WebElement questions = webElement("VAR_SELECTEDQUESTIONS");
    questions.click();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    WebElement questionNextButton = webElement("VAR_QUESTION_NEXTBUTTON");
    questionNextButton.click();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

Comment: Could you share problematic code as well??

Comment: Code is added with the question

Comment: Any idea on what is the problem???

Comment: You [need to follow this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42197200/selenium-actions-movetoelement-org-openqa-selenium-unsupportedcommandexception/42197581?noredirect=1#comment71562255_42197581), you have the same problem..:)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium Actions.movetoElement - org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42197200/selenium-actions-movetoelement-org-openqa-selenium-unsupportedcommandexception)